# Количество последовательностей из цифр C++

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть массив из 1 и 0 который заполняется

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   mas[i] = rand() % 2;
   cout << mas[i] << endl;
}
```

Надо найти количество последовательностей из двух цифр (00, 01, 10, 11)
и количество последовательностей из трех цифр (000, 001, 010, и т.д.)
Не могу сделать цикл перебора, вот что вышло

```
void secondTask(int size, int mas[]) {
int zeroZeroCounter = 0;
int zeroOneCounter = 0;
int oneZeroCounter = 0;
int oneOneCounter = 0;
int first = 0;
int second = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
 first = mas[i];
 second = mas[i+1];
    if ((first == 0) && (second == 0)) {
        zeroZeroCounter += 1;
    }
    if ((first == 0) && (second == 1)) {
        zeroOneCounter += 1;
    }
    if ((first == 1) && (second == 0)) {
        oneOneCounter += 1;
    }
    if ((first == 1) && (second == 1)) {
        oneOneCounter += 1;
    }
}
cout << "00 - " << zeroZeroCounter << endl;
cout << "01 - " << zeroOneCounter << endl;
cout << "11 - " << oneOneCounter << endl;
cout << "10 - " << oneOneCounter << endl;

}
```

оригинальная функция

Помогите с кодом или подтолкните в нужном направлении

Comment: И что именно вам мешает проходить по массиву и считать? Хотя, в общем виде, если у вас N цифр, то у вас N-1 двухциферная последовательность, и N-2 - трехциферных. Но, думаю, вас интересует не это? (это намек - писать вопросы так, чтобы их можно было понимать однозначно).

Comment: По исправленному вопросу - `i < size-1`, иначе вы выходите за границу массива. И `oneOneCounter` вы используете два раза, а `oneZeroCounter` не используете вовсе... Сам код я бы писал иначе - но с указанным исправлением должно работать и так... **Что именно** у вас не работает?

Comment: @Harry Все равно не понимаю

Comment: Не понимаю **что**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение, на которое намекал Harry.

```
void secondTask(int size, int mas[]) {

    int zeroZeroCounter = 0;
    int zeroOneCounter = 0;
    int oneZeroCounter = 0;
    int oneOneCounter = 0;
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        first = mas[i];
        second = mas[i + 1];

        if ((first == 0) && (second == 0)) {
            zeroZeroCounter += 1;
            }

        if ((first == 0) && (second == 1)) {
            zeroOneCounter += 1;
            }

        if ((first == 1) && (second == 0)) {
            oneZeroCounter += 1;
            }

        if ((first == 1) && (second == 1)) {
            oneOneCounter += 1;
            }
        }

    cout << "00 - " << zeroZeroCounter << endl;
    cout << "01 - " << zeroOneCounter << endl;
    cout << "11 - " << oneOneCounter << endl;
    cout << "10 - " << oneZeroCounter << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Я так и сделал в итоге, но оно не подсчитывает правильно последовательность 10

Comment: Вы исправили в двух местах oneOneCounter на oneZeroCounter?

Comment: Мне именно так надо сделать чтобы эти последовательности были разные

Comment: Вот проверьте - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5877ea2eb359e3e В вашем окне вывода видно, что вы выводите два раза `oneOneCounter`. Какая переменная у вас написана в строке `cout << "10 - " `?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы делал примерно так:

```
int counter[4] = {};

...

for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) 
    counter[mas[i]*2+mas[i+1]]++;
```

Понятно, что в `counter[0]` - количество 00, в `counter[1]` - количество 01 и так далее...

Comment: посмотрите, я изменил на оригинальную как сейчас у меня, я не совсем понимаю как исправить

Comment: Я вам написал - исправьте проверку в цикле и одну переменную. Что именно из написанного вам непонятно?

Comment: можно пожалуйста не в массиве показать

Comment: Все, я пас. Может, кто-то поймет, как вам объяснить, что вы выходите за границу диапазона, и что вы используете одну и ту же переменную два раза. Я писать одно и то же 10 раз времени не имею.